# Byte text file to array

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, lcd, sd-card

I'm trying to display a bitmap on gLCD 128x64, I stored the bitmap into txt file `1.txt` in a SD card this is a part of bit map  as following:

0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x80, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0,
0xC0, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00.......

I want to convert the content of this text into array:
`Unsigned char logo[]` with making a split on "`,`".

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to read the file byte-by-byte into a small character array until you get a comma or the end of file - ignoring any characters that aren't of interest (line feeds, etc).

Then for each chunk that you read you then convert it to an integer.

For example (untested):

```
char temp[5] = {0}; // should be more than enough
int pos = 0;
int bno = 0;

const char *hexchars = "0123456789abcdefABCDEFx";

while ((int ch = myFile.read()) >= 0) {
    if (ch == ',') { // We found a comma
        logo[bno++] = strtoul(temp, NULL, 16); // Base 16 conversion
        pos = 0;
        temp[0] = 0;
    } else if (strchr(hexchars, ch) != NULL) {
        if (pos < 4) {
            temp[pos++] = ch;
            temp[pos] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to know how big the `logo` array has to be beforehand.

One does, though, have to ask "Why are you storing a graphical logo as a textual representation of binary data" in the first place?  It would be far easier to just store it as a simple binary file and read the data directly into the `logo` array with a single `File::read(void *buf, size_t nbyte);` function call.  Using text as an intermediate format is both wasteful and needlessly increases complexity massively.